# M-N relationship class in geodatabase with existing linking table?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, esri-geodatabase, relationship-class

I have a parcel database with an M-N relationship (Parcels to Deeds). I have already created and populated a linking table. We have also set up two relationship classes in the geodatabase for the two 1-M relationships (Parcels-Links, Deeds-Links).

Now we want to query that in a webmap using the Esri Javascript API, so when they click on a parcel it lists the deeds. We know we can do this with two nested relationship queries, but it's cumbersome. We were hoping that we could set up the geodatabase so we could query it in one shot. It seems common enough that Esri would have a system for it.

We first tried creating a view that joins the links to the deeds, so we could do one relationship class from parcels to the view, but it will not allow us to link a relationship class to a view (is that correct?).

Then we tried creating an M-N relationship class, but it insists on creating a new linking table and I can't find an option for using an existing table.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to let it create the table, then load your linking table rows into it.

Comment: Thanks. Here is a slightly different version of the same answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110109/importing-values-into-nm-relationship-class-of-geodatabase?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was not able to get the Table to Relationship Class tool to work, but I was able to use Ben's solution, creating an empty M-N Relationship Class with no additional attributes.

The new table never shows up as a table in ArcGIS, only as a relationship class, so the normal loading tools aren't available. When I loaded it into ArcMap, it shows up as a table, so I added my additional columns there.

Then I was able to go into my database directly, and load the old table into the new with SQL (insert into ... select)